# UIPrintInteractionController not printing to full page in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uiprintpagerenderer, uiprintformatter, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I am printing a pdf from iPhone to Airprint compatible printer using Apple print document example. But I am not getting full page print from iPhone, please see the picture of what I am getting, I need the pdf to be printed on full paper lenght,width.

[image]

The code I am using for print function is given below, its the same code as in Apple print sample app,

```
    UIPrintInteractionController *controller = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    if(!controller){
        NSLog(@"Couldn't get shared UIPrintInteractionController!");
        return;
    }

    UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if(!completed && error){
            NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain, error.code);
        }
    };

    controller.delegate = self;

    // Obtain a printInfo so that we can set our printing defaults.
    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    // This application produces General content that contains color.
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    // We'll use the URL as the job name.
    printInfo.jobName = [_filePath lastPathComponent];
    // Set duplex so that it is available if the printer supports it. We are
    // performing portrait printing so we want to duplex along the long edge.
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    // Use this printInfo for this print job.
    controller.printInfo = printInfo;
    controller.printingItem = myData;
    // Be sure the page range controls are present for documents of > 1 page.
    controller.showsPageRange = YES;

    // This code uses a custom UIPrintPageRenderer so that it can draw a header and footer.
    APLPrintPageRenderer *myRenderer = [[APLPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];
//  UIPrintPageRenderer *myRenderer = [[UIPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];
    // The APLPrintPageRenderer class provides a jobtitle that it will label each page with.
//    myRenderer.jobTitle = printInfo.jobName;
    // To draw the content of each page, a UIViewPrintFormatter is used.
    UIViewPrintFormatter *viewFormatter = [docWebView viewPrintFormatter];

#if SIMPLE_LAYOUT

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:HEADER_FOOTER_TEXT_HEIGHT];
    CGSize titleSize = [myRenderer.jobTitle sizeWithFont:font];
    myRenderer.headerHeight = myRenderer.footerHeight = titleSize.height + HEADER_FOOTER_MARGIN_PADDING;
#endif
    [myRenderer addPrintFormatter:viewFormatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];
    // Set our custom renderer as the printPageRenderer for the print job.
    controller.printPageRenderer = myRenderer;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        [controller presentFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];  // iPad
    }
    else
    {
        docWebView.hidden = YES;
        [controller presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];  // iPhone
    }
```

Comment: Could you please post a link to the PDF file?

Comment: Pdf file is saved locally in my phone in documents directory.

Comment: Could you take it and upload it? Could be a problem in the way the document was created?

Comment: Here is the link to the pdf, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25454316/newform.pdf

Comment: are you talking about physical copy or just soft copy

Comment: i have tested both, physical and soft copy too..

Comment: which one iPhone you face the problem either 3.5 or 4 inch

Comment: i m aslo facing the same problem.. please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272570/printing-pdf-using-iframe-in-cordova

Answer (score 4):

I generate PDFs to print full page by drawing to a PDFcontext. I set it up with a call like this:

```
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero, nil);
```

note that because I've passed in CGRectZero for the size the context comes in its default size

```
 /*
  default pdf..
   8.5 X 11 inch
   612 x 792
   */
```

**this is only 72dpi, but its the default.  I have a trick where I zoom out before drawing to improve resolution:

```
for (int page = 0 : page < numberPages : page ++ ){
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGFloat scaleFactor = 3.0;
CGContextSaveGState(pdfContext);
CGContextScaleCTM(pdfContext, 1.0/scaleFactor, 1.0/scaleFactor);


///draw stuff
/// context size is now (612.0 * 3.0 , 792.0 * 3.0) , i.e. resolution 72.0 * 3.0 dpi..
//


CGContextRestoreGState(pdfContext);

}//page drawing loop


NSString *filePath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] //etcetc make a path];
BOOL success = [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

ok so now i have my pdf i print directly to the UIPrintInteractionController

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[self pdfView]filePath]];
   if ([UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:pdfData]) {

    UIPrintInteractionController *pr = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
      if (!completed && error) NSLog(@"Print error: %@", error);
    };

    pr.printingItem = pdfData;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
      [pr presentFromRect:tool.frame inView:self.view animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    } else {
      [pr presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    } 
  }
```

Note that I don't mess about with UIPrintPageRenderer.  I have no experience with that class, I've never needed to look into it.  But it seems to me that if its making room for a header and a footer then these are necessarily going to scale your document down in order to make space.  Try incorporating your header and footer into the document itself.  Good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
bestPaperForPageSize:withPapersFromArray:
```

Returns the print-paper object that UIKit determines to be the best for a print job based on the given page size and the paper size–imageable area combinations specific to the printer.

```
+ (UIPrintPaper *)bestPaperForPageSize:(CGSize)pageSize withPapersFromArray:(NSArray *)paperList
```

The delegate of `UIPrintInteractionController` may call this method in its implementation of the [printInteractionController:choosePaper:](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate/printInteractionController%3achoosePaper%3a) method declared in the `UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
UIViewPrintFormatter *viewFormatter = [docWebView viewPrintFormatter];
use
viewPrintFormatter *viewFormatter = [[UIPrintFormatter alloc] init];

don't need specific formatter for pdf and image